# Issues in signing the .COD file

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, .cod-file

I am facing issues in signing the .COD file for my Application.

Few days back, I installed the Signature key files on my machine which I received from the  Blackberry support. Signature Key  files were successfully installed on my machine.

Now, I want to sign my .COD file again as my .COD files have been updated. But, I am getting the following error, when I try to sign the .COD file.

The Private key could not be found.

This program requires a private key for signing all transaction between this server and the signing authority server.

The private key is contained in the sigtool.csk file which was not found.
Expected location  : C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 5.0.0\bin\sigtool.csk

Would you like to create a new key pair file.

Well, I can not create a new key pair file as it is not allowed.

Comment: Does the sigtool.csk exist in that location?  If not, where did you put it?

Comment: Review an old blog post I wrote regarding code signing, you might find it useful: http://zechariahs.org/blog/2009/02/28/blackberry-code-signing-help-p2/.

Answer (score 1):

i think in your system more than one jde or jde plugin is installed.go to bin directory of jde or eclipse plugin check for sigtool.csk.if its present, right click on signaturetool.jar and select "java platform se binary", one window will appear here browse your application.cod file and request for signature.